# Question Regarding Inverses In a Function

Tags: matrices, functions, inverse

Here is my current issue.

Our teacher asked a question related to the finding  of an inverse of 2.
Here is all of the given information:

**Define "a cross b" as such: a ☢ b = ab + (a + b). Use this new operation to evaluate the following. Find the "cross" inverse of 2.**

Here is the work that I have currently done:

**2 ☢ x = -1**
**2x + (2 + x) = -1**
**3x + 2 = -1**
  **3x = -3**
  **x = -1**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find the neutral element.  It's not $-1$, it's zero, since $$a\otimes 0=a0+a+0=a$$

Now, to find the inverse of $2$, you want $2\otimes x=0$, and then continue as you have $2x+2+x=0$, so $3x=-2$ or $x=-\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: I like your thinking, but could you please explain why it would be 0? Wouldn't it only be zero if you were attempting to find the identity?

Comment: $0$ is the $\otimes$ identity, so the inverse of $2$ is the number you $\otimes$ by $2$ to get the identity.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But further, wouldn't the inverse normally be n^-1? So wouldn't it be 1/2? For example, in a matrix you multiply a 2x2 matrix by the inverse of the 2x2 matrix in order to get the     [1   0][0   1]. Isn't that technically just making it equal to 0? Sorry for so many questions I'm trying to comprehend this.